# get a list of document from firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection `accounts` structured as follow:

[image]

Now I have a user who owns two accounts:

[image]

How do I make a query to fetch the account of this user and return it as a resolution of a promise?

Here is what I tried. It returns `[]`

```
 getAccounts(user_id, userRef) {
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            this.db.runTransaction((transaction) => {
                return transaction.get(userRef.doc(user_id)).then((userDoc) => {
                    let accounts = []
                    if (!userDoc.exists) {
                        throw "User Document does not exist!";
                    }
                    let userData = userDoc.data()
                    let accountList = userData.accounts

                    for (var id in accountList){
                        transaction.get(this.ref.doc(id)).then(ans => {
                            accounts.push(ans.data())
                        }).catch(e => {
                            console.log(e)

                        })
                    }
                    return accounts
                }).then(function (ans) {
                    res(ans)
                }).catch((e) => {
                    console.log(e)
                });
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.error(err);
                rej(err)
            });

        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a transaction, since you are just **reading** some documents. Since you want to execute, in parallel, two (or more) asynchronous methods which return a promise (i.e. the two `get()` for the accounts docs) you should use `Promise.all()`.

Something along the following lines should work:

```
getAccounts(user_id, userRef) {
   return db.collection('users').doc(user_id).get()  //replaced since I am not sure what is this.db in your case
   .then(userDoc => {
       const promises = []
       if (!userDoc.exists) {
           throw "User Document does not exist!";
       }
       let userData = userDoc.data()
       let accountList = userData.accounts

       for (var id in accountList){
           promises.push(db.collection('accounts').doc(id).get())
       })
       return Promise.all(promises)
   })
   .then((results) => {
       return results.map(doc => doc.data());
    })
    .catch(err => {
        ....
    });
 }
```

Note that I have used the "classic" definition for the `DocumentReference`s (i.e. `db.collection('users').doc(user_id)` and `db.collection('accounts').doc(id)`) since I am not 100% sure what are `this.ref` and `this.db` in your case. Just adapt as you wish!

You may also rework it with `return new Promise((res, rej) => {})` as you wish but the overall philosophy remains the same.